# Checkout TFS document through Word

Tags: tfs, ms-word, vcs-checkout

A client I am working for wants all documents we create for our project in source control (TFS). This includes requirements documents, design documents, etc.

Is there a way to check out a word document that is in TFS source control using Microsoft Word? I checked online and in Microsoft Word itself and did not see a way to do this.

I realize that I can check it out first using Team Explorer. It just seems to me that there would be a way to accomplish this in Word as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Support for TFS is not built into Word.  But there are some third party plugins that do this.  SmartOffice4TFS is one that I recently heard of, TeamSpec is another. But I have not used either before.

Answer (score 1):

That functionality isn't available.. I don't know if it's going to ...

Here is the link that I found about it:

[MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/aff94b6b-1edb-4b24-8991-889487146381/check-out-tfs-document-from-word-and-excel)